# remove runnable that has been posted asyncronously

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit

i would to remove a runnable object that has been posted in onResponse callback of Retrofit

```
handlerStaff().postDelayed(showhideAcceptPasswordAnimationRunnable, AppConfig.showhideAcceptDelay);


private static Handler handlerStaff() {
    return mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}


handlerStaff().removeCallbacks(showhideAcceptPasswordAnimationRunnable);
```

i am using the method removeCallbacks() of the Handler class to remove the runnable before it is being executed but the runnable is not being removed...

Comment: use one `Handler`, not two different ones

Comment: mainThreadHandler Handler instance is static...i use one Handler

Comment: no, you are calling `handlerStaff()` twice

Comment: the first time i call handlerStaff() to post a runnable and the second to remove the runnable before being executed...

Comment: but you are using different `Handlers`, use just one `Handler`

Comment: can you explain why am i using different Handlers in detail please?

Comment: because in method `handlerStaff` you are creating a new `Handler`, so each time you call that method a new `Handler` is created

Comment: you are absolute wright...i implemented a kind of singleton pattern..i'll post the answert right away..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to @pskink i was not using the same instance of Handler class...i implemented a king of Singleton pattern so handlerStaff() returns only the same instance of Handler object...and thus the runnable object can be removed before it is being executed...

```
private static Handler handlerStaff() {
    if ( mainThreadHandler == null ) mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    return mainThreadHandler;
}
```

return the same instance of Handler object whenever is being called..